# delegatecall call internal functions from caller contract

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, solidity-0.6.x

Is it possible to call internal functions from a function called using delegatecall?

Contract A call contract B using `delegatecall`, contract B needs to call an internal function from contract A.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible.

Delegatecall simply calls the function inside the context of the current contract. It's like saying "Run function A and do whatever you want in MY storage".

It has nothing to do with visibility, only storage.

It's a good question though, certainly nonintuitive. ✌️